# Rookie SQL inside of VB question - MSAccess 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Hey guys, can anyone help me with a simple question. I have this SQL statement below in a sub in VB within access from a button click, and I am new to this.

Here is what I typed:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
  Dim rs As Recordset
  Dim sql As String
  Dim db As Database

  Set db = CurrentDb

  sql = "SELECT * FROM Transactions"

  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

  Do Until rs.EOF
    rs.MoveNext

  Loop
  If Not rs.EOF Then

    MsgBox "test"
  End If

End Sub
```

Ok, so how do I populate this?? Essentially I am justing starting out with this, so I am wondering how do I take this simple code, and run it like a query so that the resulting recordset opens.

Thanks!

Comment: Opens into what?  Do you have a form built for it?

Comment: Be more specific about what "populate this" means.

Comment: I think he's looking for the statement he'd need inside his DO...LOOP to actualy read the data in the recordset, which he's currently not doing.

Comment: sorry i am really new to this....i am just trying to learn how to use sql in vb. and i ws thinking that if i run a query like this, there must be some way that it would "populate" a recordset...meaning that if you open the query builder and create a query and click run, you get a resulting recordset. is it the same in vb? thanks for the help guys!

Comment: If by "recordset" you mean a spreadsheet like view, you can do the same thing in code for a saved query with docmd.openquery "queryname" otherwise see my answer below.

Comment: so i still have to refer to a save query object to get to that....i can't just create the query in vba and get the same result? yes I meant like a table view of the query, only I do not want the table....i have very long top Nth queries that I want to use this for. thanks

Comment: There's nothing clear about what you want to do. In general, looping through a recordset is not the optimal way to get a job done. Instead, you want to run a single SQL statement to updates the data in a set of records. Or, you want to load a set of records in a form, and let the user browse through the records. You shouldn't be starting out with a loop through a recordset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some other remarks and advices:

1) Always indicate which type of recordset you are using. Here it seems to be a DAO recordset, so go for a complete declaration like:

```
Dim rs as DAO.recordset
```

Runing on another computer, and depending on the declaration order of ADODB and DAO libraries, the very same code can generate a bug.

2) To avoid any disturbing error message if no record is available, you can add an extra test, something like

```
if rs.recordcount = 0 then
Else
    rs.moveFirst
    ....
```

3) To browse the complete recordset with debug.print, you could do it this way. Just ad a 'm_debugLine' as string, and a 'fld' as DAO.Field in your declarations.

```
rs.MoveFirst
do while not rs.eof
    m_debugLine = ""
    for each fld in rs.fields
        m_debugLine = m_debugLine + vbTab + fld.value
    next fld
    debug.print m_debugLine
    rs.movenext
loop
```

4) you could even add a debug.print line to print out the field names before printing the data. I guess you'll find this one

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be over-complicating this. A better approach would be to set the recordsource of the form (in the property sheet) to the transactions table then drop the fields you want on the form using the visual designer.

HOWEVER, If you really must do it this way, here is the code that will replace what you have and open a spreadsheet like view of the data in the transactions table.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
   docmd.Opentable "transactions"
End Sub
```

If you want to limit the results to a query, then first build the query and save it then use the following code.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
   docmd.OpenQuery "MyQueryName"
End Sub
```

To be extremely literal, your original code DID populate a recordset (in the rs object). You can access the fields by name using code in your while loop such as

```
debug.print rs("Field1")
```

Comment: this is more for some automation processes that i need to complete. i have hundereds of query object in an access database that get run routinely, and then the resulting dataset are used for different xls reports, and charting automation in power point. which i can do with vb, just always used query builder and never bothered to learn sql in vb. so the very first thing I was trying to do is run a query and get the exact same simple result as I would with building it in the query builder. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You put your code inside the Do..Loop. This code will be evaluated for each record that is encountered.

```
Do Until rs.EOF
   Msgbox "The value for MyField is " & rst!MyField
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Ah, yes... forgot about the rs!fieldname syntax in Access. :)

Comment: I got in the habit of using rst!MyField or rst![MyField With Spaces] rather than rst("MyField") so that I could distinguish field names from function calls.

Answer (score 1):

you get at the columns of the record for the recordset like rs(0) or rs("columnname")....

if your transactions table has three columns named a, b, c you could get to it like:

```
rs(0)
rs(1)
rs(2)
```

or

```
rs("a")
rs("b")
rs("c")
```